# Finding terms of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find all terms of Fibonacci sequence that do not exceed 100. Here is my code:

```
fibonacci_sequence = [1,2]
index = fibonacci_sequence.length

# finding next term, term 3
# current index is 2
next_term = fibonacci_sequence[index - 2] + fibonacci_sequence[index - 1]
fibonacci_sequence.push(next_term)
index += 1

until next_term > 100 do
  next_term = fibonacci_sequence[index - 2] + fibonacci_sequence[index - 1]
  fibonacci_sequence.push(next_term)
  index += 1
end

p fibonacci_sequence
```

When I try to run my code, the value `144` is also included. Any idea?

Comment: Hint: Does the loop run when `next_term` is `89`?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition:

```
until next_term > 100
```

evaluates `next_term` before updating. Within the loop, you calculate the next `next_term` and add it. So your loop ends one iteration after the condition is satisfied.

You also don't need `index`, and also don't need to do the first iteration separately.

Change it to:

```
fibonacci_sequence = [1, 2]
loop do
  next_term = fibonacci_sequence[-2] + fibonacci_sequence[-1]
  break if next_term > 100
  fibonacci_sequence.push(next_term)
end
p fibonacci_sequence # => [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```